# How to undo/ go back to a previous version in a Google Form

Tags: google-forms

I deleted a certain section on my Google Form which has resulted in the deletion of the entire form.
Does any one know if there is a way to fix this?
Undo button is not working nor is the back button.
I can still access the responses but unable to get the content of the form.

Answer (score 6):

## Short answer

Google Forms doesn't include a feature to do this.

## Explanation

In contrary as occurs with Google Documents, Sheets and Slides, Google Forms doesn't have the revision history feature.

Unfortunately Google Drive doesn't keep revisions of Google Forms either.

## Suggested action

Send feedback to Google to request to add a feature to prevent the missing of form elements like questions and sections.  To do this, open the form on edit mode, then click on ? > Report a problem (bottom right).

Answer (score -2):

You can undo. Go to the top of the page where you hit send. There are three dots. Click on that to find undo!

Comment: The OP said that the form was deleted. Was you able to reproduce this behavior? Are you able to return to recover the form and to recover a previous version?

Comment: Not from a previous version but when I accidentally deleted something, I was able to recover it.

Comment: The undo feature looks that is not helpful in the context on this question: "I deleted a certain section on my Google Form which has resulted in the deletion of the entire form"